# Why is the rdd populated with empty arrays when running query_json on each row?

Tags: pyspark

The following code returns an empty array when run in pySpark. When I run it against the same data using a python kernal, it returns data as expected. I'm new to pyspark, and there must some concept I'm not understanding.

My Code:

```
def query_json(json_data, path):
    nodes = []

    def find(obj, current_path='root'):
        if current_path == path:
            nodes.append(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, dict):
            for key, value in obj.items():
                find(value, f'{current_path}.{key}')
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            for index, value in enumerate(obj):
                find(value, f'{current_path}')

find(json_data)
return nodes

path = 'root.body.data.children.data.body'
df = json_df.limit(1)
rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda x: query_json(x.body, path))
rdd.collect()
```

output: [[]]

Comment: I was able to get the data like this:                                                                                                                         from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col

df = json_df.select('body').limit(2)
(df.select(explode('body.array'))
    .select(explode('col.data.children'))
    .select('col.data.body')).show(500)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a dataframe from the json data like this. Is this the correct way?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col

df = json_df.select('body').limit(2)
(df.select(explode('body.array'))
    .select(explode('col.data.children'))
    .select('col.data.body')).show(500)
```